# Matlab to python conversion matrix operations

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, matrix

Hi I am trying to covert this distance formula for rectilinear distance from matlab to python. X1 and X2 are two matrices of two dimensional points and could be differing lengths.

```
nd = size(X1); n = nd(1); 
d = nd(2);  
m = size(X2,1);

D = abs(X1(:,ones(1,m)) - X2(:,ones(1,n))') + ...
     abs(X1(:,2*ones(1,m)) - X2(:,2*ones(1,n))');
```

I think the problem I am having most in python is appending the ones matrices with X1 and X2 since they are np.arrays.

Comment: Do you need the Python version of the code?

Comment: Yes, I need the Python version.

Comment: This helps : http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html

Comment: 'appending the ones matrices with X1 and X2' doesn't sound right.  You are indexing X1 and X2 with the ones.

Answer (score 1):

First your code:

```
octave:1> X1=[0,1,2,3;2,3,1,1]'
octave:2> X2=[2,3,2;4,2,4]'
<your code>
octave:21> D
D =
   4   3   4
   2   3   2
   3   2   3
   4   1   4
```

Matching `numpy` code:

```
X1=np.array([[0,1,2,3],[2,3,1,1]]).T
X2=np.array([[2,3,2],[4,2,4]]).T
D=np.abs(X1[:,None,:]-X2[None,:,:]).sum(axis=-1)
```

produces, `D`:

```
array([[4, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 2],
       [3, 2, 3],
       [4, 1, 4]])
```

`numpy` broadcasts automatically, so it doesn't need the `ones()` to expand the dimensions.  Instead I use `None` (same as `np.newaxis`) to create new dimensions.  The difference is then `3D`, which is then summed on the last axis.

I forgot how spoilt we are with the `numpy` `broadcasting`.  Though newer Octave has something similar:

```
D = sum(abs(reshape(X1,[],1,2)-reshape(X2,1,[],2)),3)
```